# How to find the first extrema (peaks) in a time series and extract the values in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to find the peaks in a time series. In this case I am looking for the first minimum and the first maximum (Extrema) of the following data:

```
data <- data.table(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
                   y = c(1, -1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1))
```

I am able to do it with the `stat_peaks` function of the `ggpmisc` package and the argument `span = NULL`. But now I want to extract the values of these peaks so I tried `find_peaks` also of the `ggpmisc` package, but I can't use the argument `span = NULL` anymore.
How can I extract the values of the `stat_peaks` and `stat:valleys` function? I am not able to find the peak values in the data, only in the visualization.

```
data %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
   geom_line() +
   stat_peaks(col = "red", span = NULL, ignore_threshold = 0.01) +
   stat_valleys(col = "blue", span = NULL, ignore_threshold = 0.01)
```

Comment: Are you trying to filter the max and min value? Or am I getting wrong the question?

Comment: I am already able to find/filter the first max and min values but I am not able to extract them and get them as "raw values". The result should be in this case for the max value: x = 4 and y = 3 and for the min value x = 2 and y = -1

Comment: max(data$x) will give you the max value of x, or data[which.max(data$x),] will give you the row on data with the max value of x. Is this what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

The package you are using (ggpmisc) is an extension to ggplot2 so it is just for graphing. To get the locations of the peaks & valleys you can use other packages - e.g. the functions quantmod::findPeaks and quantmod::findValleys might be one solution. See [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22974/how-to-find-local-peaks-valleys-in-a-series-of-data) for more details.

I don't know if the functions align with the package you are using- I assume they are using different criteria to find the peaks and valleys.

Note that these functions return the index of the position after any peaks in the timeseries. You can get the peaks and valleys by correcting for this:

```
 peaks <- quantmod::findPeaks(data$y) -1
 valleys <- quantmod::findValleys(data$y) -1
```